# Selenium datadriven testing - unable to fetch the data from the Numbers application (macOS)

Tags: excel, macos, numbers, data-driven-tests

I am trying to fetch the data from the `Numbers` application in **macOS**, In below code is not able to fetch the value from the cell.

```
public class Excel {

    public static String getdata(String sheetname, int rowvalue, int cellvalue)
    {
        String value = "";
        try {
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("./Excel/Logincred.xlsx");
          Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
          Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetname);
          Row r = sh.getRow(rowvalue);
          Cell c = r.getCell(cellvalue);    
          value = c.toString();   
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {   
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why reference excel in the code when you say you are using Numbers?

Comment: its just a Name of the folder and class name

Comment: And are you sure wb.getsheet() works with Numbers?

Comment: Honestly, am not sure..

Answer (score 0):

You need to append `'` before each number in your excel sheet and then your code would work completely fine.
So lets say, you have a value `4` in your excel, you need to change it to `'4` and then your read from excel would work

Comment: No luck bro.. not able to fetch the value.. i am using the value as ‘myusername.

Comment: You are fetching a string from the excel? I though you are fetching an integer, the logic that i have mentioned is for integers, for string you dont need to use `'`. And what is the error that you were getting before using `'` ?

Comment: The version of the numbers application - version 6.2.1 (6529)

Comment: not getting any exception, the cursor is there in the text box and nothing after